# combineReducers Typescript No Overload

Tags: typescript, redux

I'm running into an issue with my reducers. I am probably missing something obvious but I am running into an issue with combineReducers function.

```
export default combineReducers<ConfigCategoryState>({
  tree: treeReducer(),
  });
```

This produces the following error:

```
No overload matches this call.
No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 3, '(reducers: ReducersMapObject<ConfigCategoryState, any>): Reducer<CombinedState<ConfigCategoryState>, AnyAction>', gave the following error.
    Type 'Reducer<CategoryTree, Action<any>>' is not assignable to type 'Reducer<CategoryTree, any>'.
      Types of parameters 'state' and 'state' are incompatible.
        Type 'CategoryTree | undefined' is not assignable to type 'CategoryTree'.
          Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'CategoryTree'.
  Overload 2 of 3, '(reducers: ReducersMapObject<ConfigCategoryState, AnyAction>): Reducer<CombinedState<ConfigCategoryState>, AnyAction>', gave the following error.
    Type 'Reducer<CategoryTree, Action<any>>' is not assignable to type 'Reducer<CategoryTree, AnyAction>'.
      Types of parameters 'state' and 'state' are incompatible.
        Type 'CategoryTree | undefined' is not assignable to type 'CategoryTree'.
          Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'CategoryTree'.ts(2769)
types.ts(35, 3): The expected type comes from property 'tree' which is declared here on type 'ReducersMapObject<ConfigCategoryState, any>'
types.ts(35, 3): The expected type comes from property 'tree' which is declared here on type 'ReducersMapObject<ConfigCategoryState, AnyAction>'
```

Here is the reducer:

```
const isLoadingReducer = () =>
  buildReducer<boolean>(true)
    .handle(initCategoryTree, () => false)
    .done();
```

And the action:

```
export const initCategoryTree = createAction<CategoryTree, CategoryTree>(
  "INIT_CATEGORY_TREE",
  (tree) => tree
);
```

I'm not sure if I need to add anything else. I am getting this issue in all of my reducers so I only included one for conciseness. I know that buildReducer takes a function rather than an invocation of a function, but removing the brackets in combineReducer doesn't solve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're *calling* `treeReducer()`, not *passing a reference* to the `treeReducer` function.

Remove the parentheses, and it will be correct.

Also, don't pass generic type arguments.  `combineReducers` will infer what the correct type is.  In fact, we recommend [inferring the root state type from the root reducer](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/usage/usage-with-typescript#getting-the-state-type):

```
const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  tree: treeReducer
});

type RootState = ReturnType<typeof rootReducer>;
```

Comment: This worked! Thank you so much for your help. I didn't know that combineReducers had the capacity to infer type information

Comment: Just out of curiosity, if there isn't a root reducer is there another way to get the state type?

Comment: What do you mean "isn't a root reducer"?  There's always a root reducer in a Redux app - it's whatever reducer you've passed to `configureStore/createStore`.  If you used the "object shorthand" form of `configureStore`'s `reducer` argument, like `configureStore({reducer: {todos: todosReducer}})`, then you can infer the root state type with `type RootState = ReturnType<typeof store.getState>`: https://redux-toolkit.js.org/usage/usage-with-typescript#getting-the-state-type